# FileSystemWatcher Issue

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a windows service which has a `FileSystemWatcher` which watch a log folder for txtfiles changes.

it fires `onChanged` Event every time a logline gets written to a txtfile , i start reading for that file and i retrieve that line and then process it some way, the problem is :

the events doesnt get fired unless :

-i open the folder with windows explorer
-i keep pressing refresh (f5)

if i dont do that the events doesnt get fired !

Comment: Is your app or some other app of yours writing the loglines to the textfile or a 3rd party app?

Comment: Is the folder on a network share?

Comment: actualy for simulation purpose i made a small software which writes to the textfiles , @C.Evenhuis: its all on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this might happen when the internal buffer of the file is not flushed. Try flushing the stream after you write to it.

Comment: What if your simulation app closes the file after each entry? Does it work then?